# How to setup password-less ssh between two vagrant machines?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, vagrant

I have set up a enviroment of two machines in vagrant where I used the following CentOS image: http://developer.nrel.gov/downloads/vagrant-boxes/CentOS-6.4-x86_64-v20130427.box

Lets call the two machines master and slave.

I would like to be able to talk to the slave from master over password-less ssh, so I followed the instructions in this blog post for setting up password-less ssh:
http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/01/how-to-setup-password-less-ssh-to.html

The steps in the post would then be:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub vagrant@slave-hostname
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The steps works fine and the slave gets the master key written in authorized_keys.

The problem is that the slave keeps asking for password when I try to enter it over SSH from the master.

Are there setting in Vagrant which I need to change in order to get password-less ssh to work?

Comment: Have you change the permitions? You can try this: http://superuser.com/questions/255396/how-do-i-ssh-without-a-password-setting-up-ssh-keys-doesnt-work

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that link. BillThor had an excellent explanation which lead me to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer suggested that I have to look at the permission all the way from root to the ssh folder.

https://superuser.com/a/255411/210224

In order to solve the problem I had to add the [sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) to the home folder.

```
sudo chmod +t /home
```

Read the linked answer above for more details.